# Admin override account lockout policy w10?

Tags: windows-10

I have setup account lock out policies for to many incorrect passwords for local users on a W10 pro machine.

The lock out policy has been triggered, i am an admin for the machine and have an admin account on there, is there a way i can over ride the lockout for this standard local user ?

Comment: Are these domain accounts or local accounts?

Comment: If you have an account that is locked, as an Administrator, you can unlock it.

Comment: @music2myear they are local accounts

Comment: @Ramhound where can i do this ?

Comment: @sam - User Accounts within Computer Mangement.